# Adding plotting parameter to a temporary variable in R

Tags: r, plot

Is it possible to assign a plotting function with its arguments to a variable and use it as template?

for example, if I have something like

```
tmp_plot <- plot(my_data, xlabel="x", ylabel="y", ...)
```

could I add another argument, for example, `main="caption"` to replot the plot without typing the whole function again?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a function that is a wrapper for `plot` with `main = 'caption'`

```
mplot <- function(...) plot(..., main = 'caption')
mplot(1:10,1:10)
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I'm wondering if you are looking for the `title` function? It will add new text to an existing plot that is sitting on the interactive graphics device. There is a `dev.copy` function that attempts to make a new graph which can further be altered by `title` or `points` or any of the other base graphics functions that allow additions. See also a `savePlot` function for X11() devices. The problem with the code you offer is that most "plot" functions in the base-graphics paradigm will return NULL, so that temp_plot would be ... nothing. The possible exception are S4 plot functions that actually use lattice or ggplot2 (see below).

Contrariwise, if you are trying to save a plot as an R structure then you need to look at the lattice and ggplot2 plotting functions which do that by storing the plot data and structure in a list object.

Comment: Thanks, this answer was very helpful, I noticed this feature to add plot arguments in the ggplot2 package, so I was wondering if it would also work similarly with R's base functions, but it seems this is not the case according to the reasons you mentioned above.